# How to do a cumulative count using Raw SQl / Laravel - Eloquent ORM

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, mariadb

This is more of a SQL question than a Laravel one.

I'd like to accomplish something like the following  based on my `User` model  with the `created_at`  field. (table users in database)

| created_at | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-30 | 1 |
| 2022-05-02 | 2 |
| 2022-05-03 | 4 |

| date | created_users_to_this_date | total_users_created_to_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-05 | 2 | 3 |

Any idea on how to do so ?

What I have done so far (using Eloquent ORM) :

```php
User::query()
   ->selectRaw("COUNT(*) created_users_to_this_date, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') date")
   ->orderBy('date')
   ->groupBy('date')
   ->get();
```

Equivalent SQL request

```sql
select COUNT(*) created_users_to_this_date, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') date from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null group by `date` order by `date` asc
```

Thus returning

| date | created_users_to_this_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04 | 1 |
| 2022-05 | 2 |

I thank you for your help

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mysql version support window function, you can try to use `SUM` window function to do cumulative count

```
DB::table(DB::raw('(select COUNT(*) created_users_to_this_date, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, \'%Y-%m\') date 
    from `users` 
    where `users`.`deleted_at` is null 
    group by `date`) t1'))
->select('created_users_to_this_date','date',DB::raw('SUM(created_users_to_this_date) OVER(ORDER BY date) total_users_created_to_date'))
->get();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Just a quick question.
If I wanted to limit the result between dates e.g between now() and lastYear,
how would i do so ?

Comment: @Tanuki I think we can try to add conditions in `where` clause part

Answer (score 1):

your equivalent sql will be

```
SELECT DATE ,
  @running_number:=@running_number+created_users_to_this_date AS created_users_to_this_date
   FROM (SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS created_users_to_this_date,
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') DATE
FROM
  users 
where users.deleted_at is null 
GROUP BY `date` 
ORDER BY `date` ASC ) final
JOIN (SELECT @running_number:=0) rn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User::query()
 ->select('
 DB::raw('COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, \'%Y-%m\') = DATE_FORMAT(now(), \'%Y-%m\')) as created_users_to_this_date'),
 DB::raw('COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, \'%Y-%m\') <= DATE_FORMAT(now(), \'%Y-%m\')) as total_users_created_to_date'),
 DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') as date')
 ')->orderBy('date')->groupBy('date')->get();
```